# How to check if a password for an ssh key has been set with only the public key?

Tags: ssh, public-key, rsa

We have some SFTP-Chroot Environments where we only allow 4096bit RSA Keys for authentication and we only have the public key part from our users. But we have a policy that the user has to set a password for their private key parts.

Is there a way to check if thats true (that theyve really set a password) only by owning the public key part or maybe by setting something in openssh-server config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (with only the public key). The user may change or remove the password for the private key without affecting the server.

There is a similar question: [How to tell if a public SSH key has a passphrase](https://serverfault.com/questions/44870/how-to-tell-if-a-public-ssh-key-has-a-passphrase)

If you are implementing two-factor authentication, maybe you could consider PAM or a custom script. Making it work with some SFTP clients may be a pain though.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i already thought that its not possible but was unsure. thanks for ensure.